# python datetime, time and calendar overlapping functionalities

Tags: python, datetime, time, calendar

Every time I want to do something date related in python I get confused. There seems to be a lot of overlapping functionality amongst time, datetime and calendar modules. Also, some functionality that you would expect to be integrated in one module is spread over these three. This gets worse with different formats of dates like datetime class, timetuple, timestamp, string input and...

Does anyone know of any article or good tutorial that compares these three modules and perhaps provides a use case oriented approach.

Something like this:

To get the current timestamp use: time.time()

To convert a timetuple to timestamp use: calendar.timegm()

To convert datetime to timetuple use: datetime.timetuple()

Comment: 80-90% of the time, I don't want `calendar`.  The other 10-20% of the time I forget that it's there ...

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the state of it. I ended up rolling my own DateTime class (using mostly the `datetime` module and the `pytz` 3rd-party package) because I couldn't stand it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The Times library attempts to simplify this problem. https://github.com/nvie/times

> Times is a small, minimalistic, Python library for dealing with time conversions to and from timezones, for once and for all.
>
> It is designed to be simple and clear, but also opinionated about good and bad practices.

I haven't used the library directly but I have heard good things about it.

If you look at the code, it imports these libraries:

```
import datetime
import calendar
import pytz
```

You can get an understanding of the usage of each library from the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, there is a library called **Arrow** that tries to address the problem https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

> Arrow is a Python library that offers a sensible, human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times, and timestamps. It implements and updates the datetime type, plugging gaps in functionality, and provides an intelligent module API that supports many common creation scenarios. Simply put, it helps you work with dates and times with fewer imports and a lot less code.